# How to load resource properties in a JUnit Spring context in a multi Gradle project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I have the following project tree:

```
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   └── child
│       │   │       └── app
│       │   │           └── Application.java
│       │   └── resources
│       │       └── application-default.yaml
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── child
│                   └── app
│                       └── ApplicationTest.java
├── build.gradle
├── childA
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── child
│                   └── a
│                       ├── BaseGreeterImpl.java
│                       ├── ChildAConfig.java
│                       ├── Greeter.java
│                       └── MySpringProperties.java
├── childB
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               ├── application-test.yaml
│               └── childB.properties
├── childC
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   └── child
│       │   │       └── c
│       │   │           ├── ChildCConfig.java
│       │   │           └── PropertyGreeterImpl.java
│       │   └── resources
│       │       └── childc.properties
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── child
│                   └── c
│                       ├── TestYamlImport.java
│                       └── TestGreeter.java
└── settings.gradle
```

I have the following test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ChildCConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
public class TestYamlImport {

    @Autowired
    private MySpringProperties properties;

    @Test
    public void readChildAYaml() {
        assertThat(properties.getName()).isEqualTo("it-is-another-thing");
    }

}
```

### Expected

I expect `properties.getName()` to read the value from resource `childB` in [childB/src/main/resources/application-test.yaml](https://github.com/kopax/adk/blob/adk-spring/childB/src/main/resources/application-test.yaml).

### Result

I get `null`

### Reproduction

GitHub: https://github.com/kopax/adk/tree/adk-spring

One liner:

```
git clone git@github.com:kopax/adk.git && cd adk && git checkout adk-spring && ./gradlew build --info
```

### Question

There is a test called [childC/src/test/java/childC/TestGreeter.java](https://github.com/kopax/adk/blob/adk-spring/childC/src/test/java/child/c/TestGreeter.java#L13) in the reproduction project which prove with `childB.properties` import that **it is not a classpath issue**.

So here are my questions :

- Is spring limiting the classpath resolution somehow when using `@ConfigurationProperties` ?
- I haven't found a way to read my `application-test.yml`within a configuration `@Bean` initialized in `childA` from the **test scope** of `childB`, how is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you are using [`AnnotationConfigContextLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/javadoc) instead of (default) [`SpringBootContextLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootContextLoader.html)? The problem you are facing is not caused by file missing in the classpath (you can copy `application-test.yaml` to any `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` with the same result) but the fact that `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` does not use [`ConfigFileApplicationListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.html) that is responsible for configuring context by loading properties from well known file locations (like `application-{profile}.yaml` in your case).

You can easily compare what properties are loaded when using each loader. Firstly you can check what `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` does - just put a breakpoint at line 128 of AbstractGenericContextLoader.java file and run debugger in your favorite IDE:

[image]

Next you can investigate variable `context` -> `environment` -> `propertySources` -> `propertySourceList`. You will find 5 property sources:

[image]

None of them loads properties from config files like `application.yml` or `application.properties`.

Now let's do the same but with `SpringBootContextLoader` class. Firstly remove

```
loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class
```

in `MyEntityTest` and put a breakpoint at line 303 in SpringApplication.java file:

[image]

Here we are right before application context gets refreshed. Now let's investigate variable `context` -> `environment` -> `propertySources` -> `propertySourceList`:

[image]

The first difference we can see is that now we have 7 property sources instead of 5 as it was in the previous example. And what is most important - `ConfigFileApplicationListener.ConfigurationPropertySources` is here. This class makes application context aware of `application-{profile}.yaml` properties file existence.

[image]

So as you can see it is only a matter of using correct context loader. Replace

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ChildCConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

with

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ChildCConfig.class }, loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class)
```

or

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ChildCConfig.class })
```

as this loader is a default one when using `@SpringBootTest` annotation and you will make your test passing like a charm. I hope it helps.

Comment: No particular reason... thank you so much it really helped and thanks for the debugging information as well!